# Passar valor para a variável

Tags: php

Preciso que a variável `$idestados` receba o value do id do estado
quando uma opção for selecionada mas estou apanhando feio do ajax e jquery então quero saber se tem uma opção melhor pra fazer isso.

O `$anuncio` é uma classe que faz o select na tabela estados do bdd através do `selEstados()` e retorna um array com todas as informações, ela também possui o `selCidades(id_estado)` que faz o mesmo com a tabela cidades do bdd mas ela recebe o id do estado como parâmetro:

```
 <select name="estados" id="estados" ">                                    
    <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecione um estado</option>
    <?php 
    $estados=$anuncio->selEstados();
    foreach ($estados as $estado){
       echo '<option value="'.$estado['id'].'">'.$estado['sigla'].'- 
     '.$estado['nome'].'</option>';
    }

    ?>
 </select><br>
 <select name="cidades" id="cidades" >
    <option value="0">Selecione um estado primeiro...</option>
    <?php
        $cidades=$anuncio->selCidades($idestados);
        foreach ($cidades as $cidade){                                            
            echo '<option value"'.$cidade['nome'].'">'.$cidade['nome'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>

 </select>
```

este código

```
require_once "anuncio.php";
$anuncio =  new anuncio();
$estados= $anuncio->selEstados();
print_r($estados);
```

produz este resultado:
[image: 'array' print_r($estados);]

igualmente o

```
require_once "anuncio.php";
$anuncio =  new anuncio();
$cidades= $anuncio->selCidades();
print_r($cidades);
```

vai produzir o mesmo efeito mas com os nomes das cidades e o id do estado ao invés da sigla

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Edita a pergunta e posta o restante do seu código pra ajudar.

Comment: Depois que o PHP processa as informações, não é possível alterar as variáveis dele. Para isso você deve utilizar *AJAX* (poste como você está tentando) ou enviando as informações através de um formulário.

Comment: eu apaguei o código que tinha feito quando não funcionou ,  poderia me dar um exemplo de como funcionaria baseado no código que passei ai em cima?

Answer (score 1):

> *poderia me dar um exemplo de como funcionaria baseado no código que passei ai em cima?*

## Arquivo do formulário (*.php*):

```
<?php
    // INICIALIZAÇÃO DAS VARIÁVEIS:
    $estados = array("RIO DE JANEIRO", "ESPÍRITO SANTO", "MINAS GERAIS", "BAHIA");
?>

<!-- CARREGAMENTO DO JQUERY -->
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<select name="estados" id="estados">
    <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecione um estado</option><?php
    //$estados=$anuncio->selEstados();
    foreach ($estados as $estado) {
        echo "<option value=\"".$estado."\">".$estado."</option>";
    } ?>
</select>

<br>

<select name="cidades" id="cidades">
    <option value="0">Selecione um estado primeiro...</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#estados').on('change', function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getcidades.php',
                data: 'estado=' + $('#estados').val(),
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    console.log($('#estados').val());
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    let options;
                    $.each(data, function(chave, valor){
                        options += "<option value=\""+valor+"\">"+valor+"</option>";
                    });
                    $('#cidades').html(options);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

## Arquivo que trata a requisição do *Ajax* (*getcidades.php*):

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    if ($_POST['estado']) {
        switch($_POST['estado']) {
            case "RIO DE JANEIRO":
                $cidades = array("RIO DE JANEIRO", "SÃO GONÇALO", "NITERÓI");
                break;
            case "ESPÍRITO SANTO":
                $cidades = array("VITÓRIA", "GUARAPARY", "VILA VELHA");
                break;
            case "MINAS GERAIS":
                $cidades = array("BELO HORIZONTE", "VIÇOSA", "JUIZ DE FORA");
                break;
            case "BAHIA":
                $cidades = array("SALVADOR", "PORTO SEGURO", "JUAZEIRO");
                break;
        }
        echo json_encode($cidades);
    }
```

- Claro que está bem simples! É apenas um exemplar para você adaptar conforme sua necessidade...
- Note que para este exemplo foi utilizado a biblioteca do *jQuery* na **[versão 1.12](https://code.jquery.com/)**! Caso utilize uma versão mais recente, deve ficar atento à *depreciação* e remoção sucessiva dos atributos `success` e `error` utilizados nesse código.

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.
>
> Recomendação de leitura: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Agradecimento especial ao @[Guilherme Costamilam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91006/guilherme-costamilam) por notificar e atualizar o código com o *jQuery na versão 3*.

Comment: eu coloquei mais algumas informações na pergunta

Comment: Então, vc pode basear seu código com esse que postei. Foque também na página que trata a requisição do ajax.

Comment: o código que você passou não funciona no meu exemplo, preciso buscar as cidades que já cadastrei no banco de dados os códigos que você comentou no meu, são os array que você esta criando no seu preciso que essa pagina getCidade receba o value do estado para usar como parâmetro no select tentei aqui e não funcionou

Comment: *É apenas um exemplar para você adaptar conforme sua necessidade... * e *Então, vc pode basear seu código com esse que postei. **Foque também na página que trata a requisição do ajax*** Claro que vc vai ter que adaptar seu código (**Que não está presente na pergunta**) pra trabalhar com esse código que postei...

Answer (score 1):

O exemplo do @LipESprY ilustra exatamente o que precisa, porém `sucess` e `error` estão obsoletos e mudaram para `done` e `fail`:

```
$(function(){
    $('#estados').on('change', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getcidades.php',
            data: 'estado=' + $('#estados').val(),
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                console.log($('#estados').val());
            }
         }).done(function(data) {
                let options;
                $.each(data, function(chave, valor){
                    options += "<option value=\""+valor+"\">"+valor+"</option>";
                });
                $('#cidades').html(options);
        }).fail(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Até atualizei a minha atentando à essa atualização do *jQuery*.

Answer (score 0):

resolvi assim:

```
<select name="estados" id="estados" title="Selecione um Estado">
    <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecione um estado</option>
    <?php
      $feachall=$anuncio->selEstados();
      foreach ($feachall as $estados){
         echo '<option value="'.$estados['id'].'">'.$estados['nome'].'</option>';
      }                      
     ?>
</select><br>
<select name="cidades" id="cidades"  >
     <option value="0">Selecione um estado primeiro...</option>


</select><br>
```

o script

```
<script>
$("#estados").on("change",function(){
let idEstado = $("#estados").val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'pega_cidades.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data:{id:idEstado},
    beforeSend: function(){

        $("#cidades").html("Carregando...");
    },
    success: function(data){

        $("#cidades").html(data);
    },
    error: function(){

        $("#cidades").html("Houve um erro ao carregar");
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

e a pagina pega_cidades.php

```
<?php
    require_once'../cerebro/conectarbdd.php';
    $db = new conectarbdd;
    $conexao=$db->conectar();
    $conexao->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    $pegaCidades=$conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE 
    estados_id='".$_POST['id']."'" );
    $pegaCidades->execute();
    $fetchall = $pegaCidades->fetchAll();

    foreach ($fetchall as $cidades){

      echo '<option value="'.$cidades['nome'].'">'.$cidades['nome'].'</option>';
  }
```